# Парсинг элементов сайта со значением hide

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь спарсить сайт с помощью BS4 и Requests.
Нужный элемент при изучении через инспектор выглядит как:

```
<p class="order-quantity j-orders-count-wrapper">
Купили 
<span class="j-orders-count">более 35&nbsp;300&nbsp;раз</span></p>
```

Но при парсинге этот блок выглядит как:

```
    <p class="order-quantity j-orders-count-wrapper hide">
Купили 
<span class="j-orders-count"></span></p>
```

В тег  подставляется hide и значение не выводится.

в скрипте задаю headers:

```
headers = {'accept' : '*/*',
      'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 YaBrowser/20.2.0.1043 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}

def get_html(url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.get(url, headers=headers) 
    return r.text
```

Что сделать чтобы спарсить данный блок?

Comment: Скорее всего этот блок меняется уже после загрузки страницы через JavaScript. Проще всего через Selenium решить - полностью эмулировать загрузку через браузер. Либо придётся разбираться в этих скриптах самому и как-то их вручную запускать.

Comment: Спасибо. Селениум помог.